# Reading L1B ASTER in GRASS using r.in.aster

Tags: grass-gis, aster

I'm having a problem getting an ASTER L1B to be read in GRASS using `r.in.aster`.
The output the command shows this:

> (Wed Apr  8 17:49:03 2015) Command finished (1 sec)
>   (Wed Apr  8 17:49:37 2015)
>   r.in.aster
>   input=/home/gobel/Documents/Images/Aster/AST_L1B_00301082001131449_20110622184108_17885.hdf
>   proctype=L1B band=1 output=test Georeferencing aster image ...
>   Creating output file that is 6133P x 5675L. Processing input file
>   HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:/home/gobel/Documents/Images/Aster/AST_L1B_00301082001131449_20110622184108_17885.hdf:VNIR_Swath:ImageData1.
>   0...10...20 ...30...40. ..50...60. ..70...80.. .90...100 - done. Importing into GRASS ... Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/grass70/scripts/r.in.aster", line 168, in 
>       main()   File "/usr/lib/grass70/scripts/r.in.aster", line 129, in main
>       import_aster(proj, srcfile, tempfile, band)   File "/usr/lib/grass70/scripts/r.in.aster", line 160, in import_aster
>       outfile = "%s.%s" % (output, band) NameError: global name 'output' is not defined (Wed Apr  8 17:49:38 2015) Command finished (1 sec)

Comment: Which GRASS GIS version are you using - the officially released 7.0.0?

Comment: grgobel@LARSEN:~$ grass --version
GRASS GIS 7.0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 1347, in <module>
    parse_cmdline()
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 1259, in parse_cmdline
    message('\n' + readfile(gfile("etc", "license")))
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 139, in readfile
    f = open(path, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/grass70/etc/license'

Comment: I guess you are on Linux - but which distribution? And this error is the result of g.region? If yes, the installation is somehow broken.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. And this is the output when i try to import a ASTER image, r.in.aster

Comment: Can you post a link to an ASTER L1B HDF file for testing?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. I am using GRASS 7.0.4 from ubuntugis-unstable, and my distro is ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded this data from USGS earthexplorer (ASTER level 1T), and i uploaded them to google drive for testing https://goo.gl/3aEn8Q

Comment: here is a link to a L1B product:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9pBZlg6LlXGM29IZ1BweDZGSkU
and the metadata file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9pBZlg6LlXGcnk4eWZXUlVBV0E